# Tor Browser Bundle, or just Tor Browser

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a tag for <kbd>[Tor Browser Bundle](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor-browser-bundle)</kbd>, but I wonder if we should change this to just <kbd>Tor Browser</kbd> instead now that Vidalia is no longer "bundled" in.

Isn't "Tor Browser" now the official name?

Comment: Quick update: I've added tor-browser as a synonym of tor-browser-bundle. If there ends up being consensus then I can still set tor-browser as the primary tag name.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that we are heading towards having the name changed to Tor Browser everywhere. Mike Perry opened a ticket almost two years ago after the packages names were changed. Mike suggested to [Change Tor Browser Bundle to Tor Browser in package strings, download pages, and docs](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11193).

However the reality is that even though a lot of work has been done to update the documentation on the Tor website, there are still many uses of Tor Browser Bundle where Tor Browser is intended. This is both in [documentation on the Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#app-data-isolation) and on other sites, take for example this fairly recent guide posted on the [EFF's Surveillance Self-Defense website](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-tor-windows). In this example there is only a single occasion where Tor Browser Bundle is used interchangeably but there are plenty of other less reputable websites newcomers to Tor may be visiting for information that frequently use Tor Browser Bundle interchangeably, either because they are out of date or just inaccurate generally. **Having said all that, I don't know whether it actually matters that other documentation still uses the terms interchangeably.**

A final point to make is that the [Tor Blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-506-released) still tags releases of Tor Browser with the Tor Browser Bundle tag (as well as Tor Browser and TBB) so we would be ahead of the Tor Blog if we get rid of the Tor Browser Bundle tag.

Personally, I don't have a problem with the tag being changed.

Comment: That's why we have synonyms on tags. So "Tor Browser" would be the default name, with "Tor Browser Bundle" as a synonym.

Comment: @AndrewLott Fair enough. Given that the Tor Blog still uses both tags themselves, that might be the best way to go. The reason I said that I don't have a problem with the tag being changed is because I got the impression from Mike Perry's ticket that he wanted the name Tor Browser to eventually replace Tor Browser Bundle everywhere and also I think now the only correct way to use the the Tor Browser Bundle tag is for questions about 2 year old software. I hope other SE users who are more experienced than myself will weigh in with their thoughts before you decide what you want to do.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. And yes, I'd like a bit more consensus before going uni-mod and proceeding without.